# how can i make my program sleep for some amount of time?

Tags: c, time, sleep

I want to put my program in sleep for some desired time. but i also want that if enter is pressed then program wakes up.

```
clock_t t;
int sleep_time=10;
t=clock();
while(1){
int temp=clock()-t;
double time_now=(double)(temp)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    if(time_now>=sleep_time){
       break;
    }
    if(getchar()=='\n'){
       break;
    }

}
```

but this program will wait for input and if input is not given it will not break
How can i do this.

Comment: Use `sleep()` , Here is link for it https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

Comment: On posix systems like Linux you can use [select](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to wait for input to be available. `select` also has a timeout. Calling `select` will put the process to sleep until either input is available or the timeout expires (actually, there's also the case of being interrupted by a signal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a POSIX platform, you can use `select()`/`poll()` on standard input and with a timeout parameter:

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    fd_set inp; FD_ZERO(&inp); FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO,&inp);
    select(1,&inp,0,0,&(struct timeval){.tv_sec=1});
}
```

With signal handlers on you'll also need to watch out for `EINTR` and redo the request with the remaining time.

Unfortunately, you cannot count on either `select()` or `poll()` to give you the remaining time (`select` can and will on Linux, through the `struct timeval*` parameter, but the behavior isn't portable), so you'll need to use `clock_gettime` to calculate it yourself.